# Using pointers from one class of an array to another class of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

The goal of my program is to allow the user to enter up to 100 names for people and 100 names for cars. Then the user can "register" a car to as many people as s/he wishes by having those people point to that car.

I guess my first question would be, what's the best way to take a user's input string and place it into the array? Then what would be the best way to use a register function so that the user-specified person points to a specific car? Any help is much much appreciated!
(Vectors are not allowed for this assignment)

```css
class Person{
public:
    Person();
    void Register(Car& theirCar);
    
private:
    string personName;
};

class Car{
public:
    Car();
    
private:
    string carName;
};

Person::Person()
{
    //Set to null
}

Car::Car()
{
    //Set to null
}

int main()
{
    Car cars[101];
    Person persons[101];
    char selection;

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Currently looking at:\n";
        cout << "Person: " << endl;
        cout << "In car: " << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to (p) make a new person, (c) make a new car,\n";
        cout << "(f) find a person, (r) register a person to a car, or (q) quit\n";

        cin >> selection;

        if(selection == 'p')
        {
             cout << "What is this person's name?\n";
             
        }

        if(selection == 'c')
        {
            cout << "What is this car's name?\n";
        }

        if(selection == 'f')
        {
            cout << "Which person do you want to find?\n";
        }

        if(selection == 'r')
        {
            cout << "Which car do you wish to register to this person?\n";
        }

        if(selection == 'q')
        {
            return(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There are too many questions here, and some are opinion-based.  Perhaps you can start small, forget the `struct`s (just use an array of `std::string`s), and try to get something that works first.

Comment: I thought I gave two questions both fairly straightforward. 1. How would you take a string from a user and put it in the array? 2. How would you create a function so that a user can point from a spot in the person array to a spot in the car array?

Comment: You asked "what is the *best* way...". That's opinion-based.  If you just want one *possible* way, `std::cin >> arr[i]` would work when `arr` is an array of `std::string` and `i` is an integer.

Comment: It would appear, though, that what you want is a `std::vector` instead of a C-style array. (Since you're using C++ classes, I doubt you'd need something C-compatible.)

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to frame it that way. I appreciate the help. Do you know of a way that I can use a pointer to "register" a car to a person? This is where I have the most difficulty. And yeah I have been told using a vector would be better but I've been specified to use an array.

Comment: I think offering a rationale for not wanting to use vector (even "my assignment disallows it") could be handy, because my initial thought was certainly that you want to use `std::vector` here. Also, are you required to use raw pointers or can you use smart pointers?

Comment: You could give your `Person` class a member which is a pointer to a `Car` class.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to how that would work in a function. If the user wants to point say "John" at the person array position 3 to the car "johns_car" at the car array position 5, I would take in the position of the person array and point it to the input position in the car array through a function?

Comment: That could be done, but that wouldn't be a pointer anymore. I'm saying `void Person::Register(Car& theirCar){ this->car = &theirCar; }`

Comment: Where does "this" come from in this instance?

Comment: It is a pointer to this instance of `Person`.

Comment: so "this" would be a private member variable of person class? Sorry I'm not catching on :/

Comment: No, the answer below explains it well. Next time, type something like "@Bernard" then I will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but based on the discussion in the comments is a place to start. It attempts to provide a relatiely minimal (but complete) example of how an instance of an object may store a pointer to another object.

```
#include <string>

class Car {
public:
    Car(std::string name) : name(name) {}
private:
    std::string name {};
};

class Person {
public:
    Person(std::string name) : name(name) {}
    void registerCar(Car* car) {
        this->car = car;
    }
private:
    Car* car {nullptr};
    std::string name {};
};

int main() {
    // Create a car and a person
    Car jaguar("Jaguar");
    Person mrJagger("Mr. Jagger");

    // Associate the jaguar with the person by taking its address and
    // passing that to a Person object's registerCar method.
    mrJagger.registerCar(&jaguar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful